# How do you adjust transparency of a Basemap image (matplotlib)?

Tags: matplotlib, transparency, matplotlib-basemap

Although there isn't anything behind the basemap image, I want to adjust its transparency to make it less pronounced--basically to dull it. I have been trying to insert `alpha=0.5` into several spots in my code but it either has no effect or doesn't run.

I  have tried placing the `alpha=0.5` into the plt.figure(), Basemap(), and map.arcgisimage(). Is there another way to make the ESRI imagery display as a faded or less opaque version of itself?

```
geomap = plt.figure(figsize=(10,9))
ax1 = plt.axes([0.075, 0.01, 0.875, 0.975])
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=self.LLcrnrlon ,llcrnrlat=self.LLcrnrlat,urcrnrlon=self.URcrnrlon,
urcrnrlat=self.URcrnrlat, epsg=4269, projection='tmerc',lat_0 = self.center[0],
lon_0 = self.center[1])
map.arcgisimage(service='ESRI_Imagery_World_2D', xpixels = 2500,dpi=150,
    verbose= True, alpha=0.9)
parallels = np.arange(round(self.LLcrnrlat,1),round(self.URcrnrlat,1),0.2)
map.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[True, False, False, False],linewidth=0)
meridians = np.arange(round(self.LLcrnrlon,1),round(self.URcrnrlon,1),0.2)
map.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[False, False, False, True],linewidth=0)
```

Comment: I have no ideo about Basemap but if everything else fails, you could place a semitransparent white [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) across the whole axis area to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You must use .set_alpha() upon the image.

```
# etc.
img = map.arcgisimage(service='ESRI_Imagery_World_2D', xpixels=2500, dpi=150, verbose= True)
img.set_alpha(0.2)
# etc.
plt.show()
```